# Xen VM Login Access Reset or Alternate Method

Tags: xen

I’m new to managing Xen servers and currently have a container that’s experiencing issues with network connection.  The VM (from what I can tell) is starting up normally but doesn’t seem to have any network connectivity.  I’ve attempted to access the VM by using “xm console vmName” and get a login prompt.  I’ve tried a few logins that were provided to me but so far none work.  Is there any way to reset the login to get into the VM?  Or is there an alternate method of getting into it (from the server) in a similar manner to how Virtuozzo uses “vzctl enter CTID”?  Any help is greatly appreciated.